# Multiple object types references in Django

Tags: django, django-models, orm

We are currently running with the following configuration to avoid other issues. 
So for the question: let's assume that this is a must and we can not change the Models part.

At the beginning we had the following models:

```
class A(Model):
    b = ForeignKey(B)
    ... set of fields ...

class B(Model):
    ...
```

Then we added something like this:

```
class AVer2(Model):
    b = ForeignKey(B)
    ... ANOTHER set of fields ...
```

Assuming an object of `type B` can only be referenced by either `A` or `AVer2` **but never both**:

Is there a way to run a query on B that will return, at runtime, the correct object type that references it, in the query result (and the query has both types in it)?

You can assume that an object of type B holds the information regarding who's referencing it.

I am trying to avoid costly whole-system code changes for this.

EDIT:
Apparently, my question was not clear. So I will try to explain it better. The answers I got were great but apparently I missed a key point in my question so here it is. Assuming I have the model B from above, and I get some objects:

```
b_filter = B.objects.filter(some_of_them_have_this_true=True)
```

Now, I want to get a field that is in both A and AVer2 with one filter into one values list. So for example, I want to get a field named "MyVal" (both A and AVer2 have it) I don't care what is the actual type. So I want to write something like:

```
b_filter.values(['a__myval', 'aver2__myval'])
```

and get something like the following in return: [{'myval': }] 
Instead, I currently get [{'a__myval': , 'aver2__myval': None}]

I hope it is clearer.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say query, do you mean `B.objects.filter(some_query)` or just accessing the model in views like `B.aver2`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I mean a query set.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct object type"? It's like now B can be one of two types, "A" and "AVer2" types? You want query set with B objects only from one of these "types", or more like query set of A or/and AVer2 objects for given B? Please, give some examples of what exactly you want to get from query sets.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can not make your exact need.

Long answer: The first thing that came to my mind when I read your question is [Content Types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/), [Generic Foreign Keys and Generic Relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)

Whether you will use "normal" foreign keys or "generic foreign keys" (combined with Generic Relation), Your `B` instances will have both `A field` and `AVer2 field` and this natural thing make life easier and make your goal (B instance has a single Field that may be A or Avr2) unreachable. And here you should also override the `B model save method` to force it to have only the A field and the Avr2 to be None or A to be None and Avr2 to be used. And if you do so, don't forget to add `null=True, blank=True` to A and Avr2 foreign key fields.

On the other hand, the opposite of your schema makes your goal reachable:
`B` model references `A` and `Avr2` that means that `B` model has ONE `generic foreign key` to both `A` and `Avr2` like this: (this code is with Django 1.8, for Django 1.9 or higher the import of GenericRelation, GenericForeignKey has changed)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.generic import GenericRelation, GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


class B(models.Model):
    # Some of your fields here...
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True, blank=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    # Generic relational field will be associed to diffrent models like A or Avr2
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')


class A(models.Model):
    # Some of your fields here...
    the_common_field = models.BooleanField()
    bbb = GenericRelation(B, related_query_name="a")  # since it is a foreign key, this may be one or many objects refernced (One-To-Many)


class Avr2(models.Model):
    # Some of your fields here...
    the_common_field = models.BooleanField()
    bbb = GenericRelation(B, related_query_name="avr2")  # since it is a foreign key, this may be one or many objects refernced (One-To-Many)
```

Now both A and Avr2 have "bbb" field which is a B instance.

```
a = A(some fields initializations)
a.save()
b = B(some fields initializations)
b.save()
a.bbb = [b]
a.save()
```

Now you can do `a.bbb` and you get the `B` instances

And get the `A` or `Avr2` out of `b` like this:

```
b.content_object  # which will return an `A object` or an `Avr2 object`
```

Now let's return to your goals:

- Is there a way to run a query on B that will return, at runtime, the correct object type that references it, in the query result (and the query has both types in it)?

Yes: like this:

```
B.objects.get(id=1).content_type  # will return A or Avr2
```

- You wanna perform something like this: `b_filter = B.objects.filter(some_of_them_have_this_true=True)` :

  from django.db.models import Q

  filter = Q(a__common_field=True) | Q(avr2__common_field=True)

  B.objects.filter(filter)
- Getting  `[{'a__myval': , 'aver2__myval': None}]` is 100% normal since `values` is asked to provide two fields values. One way to overcome this, is by getting two clean queries and then chain them together like so:

  from itertools import chain

  c1 = B.objects.filter(content_type__model='a').values('a__common_field')

  c2 = B.objects.filter(content_type__model='avr2').values('avr2__common_field')

  ```
  result_list = list(chain(c1, c2))
  ```

Please notice that when we added `related_query_name` to the generic relation, `a` and `avr2` has become accessible from `B` instances, which is not the default case.

And voilà ! I hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want to get in query set.

I assumed that you want set of "correct object types" that "has both types in it", so in fact you want set of related class types (like `[<class 'main.models.A'>, <class 'main.models.A2'>]`). If that is not the case, I can change answer after more specific details in comments.

This is solution for that "class list", you can use it to get what you precisely want.

```
# Our custom QuerySet that with function that returns list of classes related to given B objects
class CustomQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def get_types(self, *args, **kwargs):
        all_queryset = self.all()
        return [b.get_a() for b in all_queryset]

# Our custom manager - we make sure we get CustomQuerySet, not QuerySet
class TypesManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return CustomQuerySet(self.model)


class B(models.Model):
    # some fields

    # Managers
    objects = models.Manager()
    a_types_objects = TypesManager()

    # Get proper A "type"
    def get_a(self):
        if self.a_set.all() and self.a2_set.all():
            raise Exception('B object is related to A and A2 at the same time!')
        elif self.a_set.all():
            return A
        elif self.a2_set.all():
            return A2
        return None


class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(
        B
    )


class A2(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(
        B
    )
```

And now you can use it like this:

```
>>> from main.models import *
>>> B.a_types_objects.all()
<CustomQuerySet [<B: B object>, <B: B object>]>
>>> B.a_types_objects.all().get_types()
[<class 'main.models.A'>, <class 'main.models.A2'>]
>>> B.a_types_objects.filter(id=1)
<CustomQuerySet [<B: B object>]>
>>> B.a_types_objects.filter(id=1).get_types()
[<class 'main.models.A'>]
```

Using `a_types_objects` works like normal `objects`, but it returns CustomQuerySet, which has extra function returning list of class.

EDIT:

If you worrying about changing a lot of `B.objects.(...)` into `B.a_types_objects.(...)` you could just set your main manager to TypesManager like that:

```
class B(models.Model):
    # some fields

    # Override manager
    objects = TypesManager()
```

Rest of your code will remain intact, but from now on you will use CustomQuerySet instead of QuerySet - still, nothing really changes.